# Writing and reading JSON with Libgdx

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx

Very confused with `JsonBeans` from Libgdx. Trying to save & load game progress to local storage. Initializing file:

```
file=Gdx.files.local(FILENAME);
```

Reading json:

```
if (file.exists()) {
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader();
        JsonValue jv = jsonReader.parse(file.reader());
        levels = jv.getInt(LEVELS, 1);
}
```

App dies with `NullPointerException` at `levels = jv.getInt(LEVELS, 1);` (`jv` is `null`).

But writing doesn't work too, output file is empty:

```
Json json=new Json(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
json.setWriter(file.writer(true));
json.writeObjectStart();
json.writeValue(LEVELS, levels);
json.writeObjectEnd();
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should be okay. Does your file have a type defined somewhere? Such as in your fields?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Gdx.files.internal instead of Gdx.files.local because you may not have permissions to write to and read from local storage.

For desktop run as administrator (i think its enough)

For android add write/read permissions to android manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Goddamn, tutorial at Libgdx wiki is extremely uninformative.
First of all never mentioned what you need to set `Writer` to `Json` instance, secondly after reading the feeling remains that all the work on recording json on disc was done by `Json` class but it isnt. You need to do this by yourself:

```
file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(progress), false);
```

After that all worked. Thanks everyone.